# Entity Framework 6 T4 Get EntitySet Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4, entity-framework-6.1

I am utilizing the T4 template in EF 6.1.3. Specifically I am creating some additional classes when generated. Stubbing out some basic CRUD methods. I need to access the EntitySet name. The T4 iterates over...

```
var itemCollection = new EdmMetadataLoader(textTransform.Host, textTransform.Errors).CreateEdmItemCollection(inputFile);
```

Those objects are of type `EntityType`. I need to find the associated `EntitySet.Name` property.

I am stumped and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging through some other T4 templates I found a solution. It appears that in previous versions the EF template would utilize the `MetadataLoader` class and now there is a custom EdmMetadataLoader class in the file itself. This new class did not expose any access to the `EntitySet` itself.

After getting the Entity collection via...

```
var itemCollection = new EdmMetadataLoader(textTransform.Host, textTransform.Errors).CreateEdmItemCollection(inputFile);
```

You can get access to the container...

```
var container = itemCollection.OfType<EntityContainer>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Then in the iteration over the entities...

```
    foreach (var entity in typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<EntityType>(itemCollection))
    {
        fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");
        var entitySet = container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>().FirstOrDefault(set => set.ElementType == entity);
        ...
    }
```

Not 100% sure if this is the proper approach, but it does the job and I get the `EntitySet` name in following property...

```
entitySet.Name
```

Comment: Hi, Seven years later, I use your code. It works perfectly.